# A DIV's style width:"100%" seemingly causes a scroll bar due to lack of fix-width parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As asked and explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585672/scroll-bar-using-100-width-div), the problem with the DIV's width set to 100% is that it'll get **the** ***window*'s** width and not the enclosed BODY element.

The solution suggested is to place an auxiliary DIV between BODY and the actual DIV and make its width fix. But that just puts the issue to the next level, doesn't it?

Since I don't know the screen size of my users' viewers (let's call it platform independence - a term I've heard somewhere is good to keep in mind when developing for the web, hehe), I need the main-all-mighty-rooted-and-parentest DIV to be **filling out** all available space **without sticking out**.

Of course, setting fix width on BODY won't work. Should I go ugly and pull the width of the part of the window that isn't the window, double it (once for each side) and retract that to set the fix width of some root DIV element?!

And if so - how?! I'm unclear on how to obtain the magic width (which, however, might be googleable) but mostly I'm unsure how to enter that parameter into the static CSS file. Will I have to do that dynamically using jQuery and *ready* function?

## Edit

I executed this line from the console.

$("body")[0].outerHTML

The result was as follows - still displaying the scroll bar.

```
<body style="width: 600px;">
  <div id="mapDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">!</div>
</body>
```

Then I executed this line.

```
$("#mapDiv")[0].style.position = ""
```

Poof, the scroll bar is gone. I thought *absolute* was the default setting... Apparently it isn't. There's the problem.

Comment: This is why practically no ones web site is 100%. Most sites (including this one) have a fixed width portal centred in the middle of the page. Do this it'll make your life 10000% easier.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. A div that's 100% wide with no other HTML on the page won't cause any scrollbars (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bD9xw/). Please post the specific code you're having issues with.

Comment: @j08691 i guess here as in linked previous question: http://jsfiddle.net/34TM4/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff - but all that shows is two divs, one with a set width and one with a percentage. And it works as I'd expect it to. Nothing strange IMO.

Comment: Aren't div elements 100% wide by default anyway?

Comment: *style width:“100%” causes a scroll bar* this isn't true

Comment: @nnnnnn, depends on the display property

Comment: @Liam as nnnnnn say by default .... the answer is Yes always by default are block elements then 100% wide.

Comment: @j08691 i'd expect the same as you

Comment: @Liam - Is there a `display` setting where it won't default to full width that would also make any sense to use when the OP wants it to be 100% of the body?

Comment: @nnnnnn, inline-block would do this, with 0 padding. But your web page will shift around depending on the size of the browser. Unless your planning on having a series of divs that move dynamically (like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)) I'd avoid this.

Comment: @j08691 Please see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/HU3Gu/2/). I get scroll bars.

Comment: Your padding is causing the scroll bar. This can be chnaged with the box-sizing property. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HU3Gu/3/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Downvoter: I can't read minds sadly.   :)   Please elaborate on what needs to be changed in the question.

Comment: But of course you get scroll bars is the basic of box model ... total width is equal to width+margin+padding+border

Comment: @Danko My bad. I was sure I had only zero there. Some spook must have added the "4". Sorry. Now it works in the fiddle. No idea why it doesn't at my stuff. I'll reload and try again - might be something deeper in the structure. Thanks! Appreciate the patience.

Comment: @j08691 Please see the edit. Found the cause.   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your edit if you have that code then you are stretching your `body` tag to `600px` and the `<div>` inside with absolute position and `width 100%`.

First the default for `position` is `static`.

Since you are using absolute position this happen, is taken off the DOM and search for a new containing block:

> The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor

If you don't set the body with any `position` value then the `div` is off and takes values in relation to another parent in this case is the window or `<html>` tag.

Then if you inspect the element is with the dimensions of `html` tag but positioned where he was in this example http://jsfiddle.net/wZ57C/. Is causing scroll because has 100% dimensions but positioned where body begins wich is at margin 8px aprox. Here you solve the scroll just adding position `top:0 left:0` check here http://jsfiddle.net/wZ57C/1/.

But if you want the div be `100%` of the body and `position:absolute` then make the body the relative parent http://jsfiddle.net/wZ57C/2/.

Comment: Godlike answer: +1. In fact, it was such a well-formulated answer that I'm almost considering to bounty it. (But I'm a bit restrictive on bountying because I got downvoted and that makes me parsimonious).   ;)

Comment: @KonradViltersten No problem mate glad to help you that edit makes all things clear about the question.